# Element visibility inside tooltip

Tags: wpf, tooltip

I've a tooltip which contains miscellaneous textblocks and I want to hide or display them dynamically. I've already done dynamic visibility with other tags outside tooltips and it worked perfectly (using an appropriate converter of course), but inside no one wants to work.

UserControl :

```
<ToolTip x:Key="directoriesTooltip">
         ...
         <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{x:Static Internationalization:Resources.PROPERTY_NAME}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontWeight="Bold"
                   Visibility="{Binding Path=IsMyTooltipVariableVisible, Source=myUC, Converter={StaticResource booleanToVisibilityCollapsedConverter}}"/>
         <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="{Binding Nom}"
                   Visibility="{Binding Path=IsMyTooltipVariableVisible, Source=myUC, Converter={StaticResource booleanToVisibilityCollapsedConverter}}"/>
 </Tooltip>
```

MainWindow :

```
<MyUserControl:myUC
       IsMyTooltipVariableVisible="{Binding Application.IsMyTooltipVariableVisible, ElementName=Window}"
/>
```

Comment: Try to pass data via DataContext

Answer (score 0):

One of the reason may be tooltip not part of visual tree so not working.